# Does iPad rotate right sooner than it rotates left (or up or down)?

Tags: ipad

If I don't have screen rotation lock turned on on my iPad 2 (OS 5.1) and am trying to use it in portrait mode, it's constantly rotating to the right when I don't want it to. Since it felt overly sensitive, I did a test to see how far it would have to tilt off of flat to rotate to a given direction.

To change rotation to up, down, or left, I needed to tilt it maybe 40 degrees off of flat. To change to right rotation, though, it only took a tilt of maybe 20 degrees.

I have the 'Clinometer' app (a fancy level), and its readings seem more or less accurate, so it doesn't seem like a problem with the accelerometer. Do others experience the same thing? Is there any setting I can change to tweak this?

Comment: I cannot duplicate this on my ipad gen3, it rotates at the same angle off of center whether going clockwise or counterclockwise.  Would be nice if some iPad 2 users tested their units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tried with an iPad (3rd gen) running 5.1, there doesn't *seem* to be a difference when I tilted left or right. At least, not a 20° difference.

But there *could* be. Since starting from iPad 2 there's the Smart Cover, people are more likely to tilt the iPad to the right, to have it in "typing mode" so Apple could have lowered the angle necessary to rotate the screen.

Comment: Thanks for the data point...no word on the iPad 2, though I'd think this is a software decision so I can't see why it would differ. Maybe I'll drag it down to the local Apple Store and ask there...